# Why doesn't the match operator match anything?

Tags: html, perl

I'm trying to parse this HTML block:

```
<div class="v120WrapperInner"><a href="/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faclk%3Fsa%3DL%26ai%3DCKJh--O7tSsCVIKeyoQTwiYmRA5SnrIsB1szYhg2d2J_EAhABIJ7rxQ4oA1CLk676B2DJntmGyKOQGcgBAaoEFk_Qyu5ipY7edN5ETLuchKUCHbY4SA#0%26num%3D1%26sig%3DAGiWqtwtAf8NslosN7AuHb7qC7RviHVg7A%26q%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%253Fv%253D91sYT_8CN8Q%2526feature%253Dpyv%2526ad%253D3409309746%2526kw%253Dsusan%25252#0boyle&amp;adtype=pyv&amp;event=ad&amp;usg=bR7ErKA_3szWtQMGe2lt1dpxzHc=" title="The Valley Downs Chicago"><img class="vimg120" alt="The Valley Downs Chicago" src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/91sYT_8CN8Q/1.jpg">
```

to capture the redirect link:

```
/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faclk%3Fsa%3DL%26ai%3DCKJh--O7tSsCVIKeyoQTwiYmRA5SnrIsB1szYhg2d2J_EAhABIJ7rxQ4oA1CLk676B2DJntmGyKOQGcgBAaoEFk_Qyu5ipY7edN5ETLuchKUCHbY4SA#0%26num%3D1%26sig%3DAGiWqtwtAf8NslosN7AuHb7qC7RviHVg7A%26q%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%253Fv%253D91sYT_8CN8Q%2526feature%253Dpyv%2526ad%253D3409309746%2526kw%253Dsusan%25252#0boyle&amp;adtype=pyv&amp;event=ad&amp;usg=bR7ErKA_3szWtQMGe2lt1dpxzHc=
```

and video title:

```
The Valley Downs Chicago
```

When I use this simple Perl code:

```
foreach $_ (@promotedVideos)
{
   if (/\s<div class="v120WrapperInner"><a href="([^"]*)" title="([^"]*)"><img/six)
   {
     print $1;
     print $2;
   }
}
```

nothing prints. While I'm troubleshooting this, I thought I'd ask you the experts if you see anything wrong or problematic.  Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Try to remove `\s` from your regexp

Comment: Don't parse HTML using regular expressions. Use one of the excellent HTML parsers on CPAN.

Comment: Even though I have stood up for parsing HTML with regular expressions in very simple cases, this is a case where I'd side with Sinan. Those regexes are just too nasty and you're just making life more difficult for yourself further down the road.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your /x regex modifier messes something with whitespaces. Remove it.

That is, it should be

```
if (/\s<div class="v120WrapperInner"><a href="([^"]*)" title="([^"]*)"><img/si)
```

/x makes perl ignore whitespaces inside regex, making your regex equivalent of following:

```
/\s<divclass="v120WrapperInner"><a href="([^"]*)"title="([^"]*)"><img/six
```

that will not match.

Also that \s at the beginning may brake things.

This is the code I've used for testing:

```
use strict;


my $inp = '<div class="v120WrapperInner"><a href="/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faclk%3Fsa%3DL%26ai%3DCKJh--O7tSsCVIKeyoQTwiYmRA5SnrIsB1szYhg2d2J_EAhABIJ7rxQ4oA1CLk676B2DJntmGyKOQGcgBAaoEFk_Qyu5ipY7edN5ETLuchKUCHbY4SA#0%26num%3D1%26sig%3DAGiWqtwtAf8NslosN7AuHb7qC7RviHVg7A%26q%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%253Fv%253D91sYT_8CN8Q%2526feature%253Dpyv%2526ad%253D3409309746%2526kw%253Dsusan%25252#0boyle&amp;adtype=pyv&amp;event=ad&amp;usg=bR7ErKA_3szWtQMGe2lt1dpxzHc=" title="The Valley Downs Chicago"><img class="vimg120" alt="The Valley Downs Chicago" src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/91sYT_8CN8Q/1.jpg">';

print "$inp\n";

if ( $inp =~ /<div class="v120WrapperInner"><a href="([^"]*)" title="([^"]*)"><img/si )
{
 print "m:\n$1\n$2\n";
}
```

Comment: hmmm...that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I've just tested it, it works perfectly. But I've removed \s at the beginning.

Comment: perfect!  the "\s" was causing the problem.  thanks so much!  why is that"\s" problematic?

Comment: Because it reqires a whitespace before opening angle bracket.

Comment: This is one of the reasons people shouldn't blindly do anything Perl Best Practices says. If you don't understand the match operator options, don't use them.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is not exactly what you are asking, but I think (based in this and your older question) that you are parsing HTML.

Let me tell you this: regexes aren't the solution. You should use [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) to parse HTML documents, because HTML documents are horribly messy.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(\*DATA);
foreach my $div ($root->find_by_tag_name('div')) {
    if ($div->attr('class') eq 'v120WrapperInner') {
        foreach (my $a = $div->find_by_tag_name('a')) {
            print "m:\n", $a->attr('href'), "\n", $a->attr('title'), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is good that you are gaining experience with regex in perl, but for this type of work you might consider using a DOM parser like [XML::DOM](http://www.cgi101.com/modules/XML.dom.html).

Answer (score 0):

G'day,

If you're having problems understanding regexp's can I suggest having a read of the regexp intro in Dale Dougherty's excellent book "sed & awk" ([sanitised Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565922255)).

Definitely one of the best intro's to regexp's around.

HTH

cheers,

Comment: This appears to use an advertising/referral link, rather than going directly to http://www.amazon.com/dp/1565922255/ ?

Comment: @Peter, oops. my late night mistake. it's not a complete referral link as there's no id in it tho. I've changed to to point to the proper vanilla link.

Comment: Actually, when I go in and look at the raw markdown, the link **does** in fact point to the vanilla amazon.com/dp/ISBN-10

Comment: Hmm, so this is something SO is doing. :/ Not sure why - there's no need to mask links with Amazon referrals. Due to more SO stupidity, I had to do a dummy edit to your post so I could remove my previous downvote.

Comment: Please stop downvoting this answer. It is SO that is rewriting the links now. See this post on meta <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links>

Comment: Unfortunately, whoever the downvote(s) are have no way of knowing unless they manually come back to check (something I always try to do), because SO doesn't have any form of 'you commented/voted on this and now things have changed' notification - there's a meta request out there for that, but then it's been around since UserVoice was used, so not sure it'll get implemented any time soon.